# How do I get children of a Document in Android, sorted by name?

Tags: android

I'm trying to get and display the children of a Document in Android.

The default sorting seems to be creation date, but I want them sorted by name. This is what I've tried:

```
Uri childrenUri = DocumentsContract.buildChildDocumentsUriUsingTree(rootUri, DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(rootDocumentUri));
Cursor rootCursor = getContentResolver().query(childrenUri,
                new String[]{DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_DISPLAY_NAME, DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_DOCUMENT_ID, DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_MIME_TYPE},
                null, null, DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
```

This gets the children, but ignores the sorting clause.
Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Have you tried sorting it after getting the result?